# Using a User Defined Function as a constraint within a temporary table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, constraints, user-defined-functions, temp-tables

I am trying to create a temp table that uses a UDF in a constraint. I'm getting the following error message:

> Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot find either column `dbo` or the user-defined function or aggregate `dbo.CK_LoseTeamSportExists`, or the name is ambiguous.

I've tested the function and it works in other contexts. Any idea?

All code below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CK_LoseTeamSportExists
(
    @loseteam     INT,
    @sportid      INT
)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @return BIT  
    IF EXISTS 
       (
           SELECT    TeamID,
                 sportid
           FROM  Link_TeamSport
           WHERE     (TeamID = @loseteam AND SportID = @sportid)
       )
        SET @return = 1
    ELSE
        SET @return = 0

    RETURN @return
END
GO

CREATE TABLE #check
(
    SportID        INT,
    WinTeamID      INT,
    LoseTeamID     INT,
    CHECK          ((dbo.CK_LoseTeamSportExists(LoseTeamID, SportID) = 1))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
USE [tempdb]
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CK_LoseTeamSportExists
(
    @loseteam     INT,
    @sportid      INT
)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @return BIT  
    IF EXISTS 
       (
           SELECT    TeamID,
                 sportid
           FROM  Link_TeamSport
           WHERE     (TeamID = @loseteam AND SportID = @sportid)
       )
        SET @return = 1
    ELSE
        SET @return = 0

    RETURN @return
END
GO

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#check')>0
DROP TABLE #check
GO

CREATE TABLE #check
(
    SportID        INT,
    WinTeamID      INT,
    LoseTeamID     INT,
    CHECK          ((dbo.CK_LoseTeamSportExists(LoseTeamID, SportID) = 1))
)
```

Comment: Note: Works without any modification to your original script in SQL Server 2014